# Update query with PHP and PDO doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem to make an UPDATE request using PDO.

I have a problem in my syntax somewhere but i don't know where..

Here is my code :

```
<?php



$PARAM_hote='aaaaaaaa'; 

$PARAM_port='3306';

$PARAM_nom_bd='bbbbbbbbbbb'; 

$PARAM_utilisateur='cccccccccccccc'; 

$PARAM_mot_passe='ddddddddddd';

// Create connexion to BDD

$connexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$PARAM_hote.';port='.$PARAM_port.';dbname='.$PARAM_nom_bd, $PARAM_utilisateur, $PARAM_mot_passe);



try {



    $idAnnonce = $_POST['idAnnonce'];


    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE `annonces` SET `etat` = `offline` WHERE `id` = :idAnnonce ";

    $resultats = $connexion->prepare($sqlUpdate);

    $resultats->bindValue(':idAnnonce', $idAnnonce, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $resultats->execute();



    // Check if request is success
    echo $resultats->rowCount();



} catch(Exception $e) {

    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';

    echo 'N° : '.$e->getCode();

}



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE `annonces` SET `etat` = `offline`...
```

to

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE `annonces` SET `etat` = 'offline'...
```

Put quotes around "offline", and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I recently commented a similar..

set error mode for PDO as a:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

**Only then** you can catch all DB-errors with your **try/catch** block and see what's happen...

see doc: [PDO::setAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)